# field missing in email results when enter key used in text area php

Tags: php, html

I have several forms which are now sent via php after a server change, so I am a fail at php :-(

But when the enter key is used in the forms text area ie

This (enter key)
is (enter key)
a (enter key)
Test

The field is completely omitted from my email results.

Any ideas

html code

```
<label>Please provide any further details of your request below.</label>      
<textarea name="further_details" rows="6" id="furtherdetails"></textarea>

<?php
```

// quick form to email function by RT
// Modify at will

```
function IsInjected($str)
{
$injections = array('(\n+)',
       '(\r+)',
       '(\t+)',
       '(%0A+)',
       '(%0D+)',
       '(%08+)',
       '(%09+)'
       );

$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";

if(preg_match($inject,$str))
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
}

function processText($text) {
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = trim($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
return $text;
}


$formname=$_POST['formname'];
$spamcode=$_POST['spam_preventer_code'];

switch ($formname) {
    case 0: $to='someone@anemail.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=42;
        $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
    case 1: $to='someone@anemail.com';
        $spamcodecheck=42;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
    case 3: $to='someone@anemail.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=42;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
    case 4: $to='someone@anemail.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=73;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
        case 5: $to='someone@anemail.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=48;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
        case 6: $to='someone@anemail.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=64;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
        case 7: $to='someone@anemail.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=48;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
}



if (!empty($to)) { 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($spamcode==$spamcodecheck) {
        $message="Form Contents \n\n";
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if(!IsInjected($value)) $message=$message.$key."=[".processText($value)."]\n";
        }

        $subject = "Form $formname submission";
        mail($to,$subject,$message);
        //echo "Mail Sent. Thank you, we will contact you shortly.";
        $header="Location: $thankyoupage";
            header($header); 
    } else {
        echo "Bad Spam Code, please go back and try again.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No form submit in post data";
}
} else {
echo "Bad Form Name.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that your function `IsInjected` is too restrictive for the `textarea`-field. If you are using (enter key) in your input, then you should allow `\n` and `\r` (currently all fields are skipped in your email, if they contain one or more of those characters).

Try modifying your function as follows:

```
function IsInjected($str) {
    $injections = array(
        '(\t+)',
        '(%08+)',
        '(%09+)'
    );

    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";

    return preg_match($inject, $str);
}
```

If you do not like those characters in your email, then you can still extend your `processText` function to eliminate them.

Hope that helps